# Data is not entered into the database mysql laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I used this code in my controller to insert data into **fund** table.

```
public function postInvestorTopup(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->user->findOrFail(auth()->user()->id);
    $lender = $this->lender->whereUserId($user->id)->firstOrFail();
    $l_id = DB::table('lender')->where('user_id',$user->id)->first()->id;
    $inputList = $request->all();
    $investorTopup = array();
    foreach ($inputList as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, 'fund') !== false){
            if($value != "")
            {
                $fund = new Fund;
                $fund->lender_id = $l_id;
                $fund->fmamt = $value;
                $fund->refdc = $value;
                $fund->ftype = '01';
                $fund->fdesc = $value;
                $fund->fstat = 'pending';
                $fund->fdate = $value;
                $fund->sign  = 'Debit';
                $fund->save();
                array_push($investorTopup, $fund);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($investorTopup as $fund){
        $fund->transid = date("ym").'03'.str_pad($fund->id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $fund->save();
    }
```

Am I have a mistake so that data is not entered into the database?
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: You try to store $value for each attribute. Please get the attribute value from $value. Ex: $value['name'] or $value->name like these..

Comment: @FilipKoblański , Nothing happen, just return redirect to the destination page.

Comment: @RamaDurai , that didn't work, nothing happened

Comment: @ardi what is the result of return $request->all()..?

Comment: @RamaDurai that is for Retrieving All Input Data . but the data is not entered

Comment: @ardi please show your input data structure and we can help you..

Comment: on a sidenote: you are saving the data at two places: `$fund->save();`

Answer (score 0):

Here in get method we are passing name of fields from where we input data 
Use this method to input data to DB

```
$user = new customer;

        $user ->name=input::get("name");
        $user ->email=input::get("email");
        $user ->country=input::get("country");
        $user ->gender=input::get("gender");

        $user->save();
```

Try this one hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I've found my solution by change my method

this is the code

```
public function insertFund($request,$lender, $ftype, $sign)
{
    $fmamt = str_replace(".","",$request->fmamt );
    $fdesc = $request->fdesc;
    $fdate = $request->fdate;
    $trnsfer  = $request->file('upload_trnsfer');   
    $transid = date("ym")."01";      

    if($fdesc == null)
    {
        $fdesc = '';
    }
    $fund = $this->fund->create([
        'lender_id' => $lender->id,
        'transid' => $transid,
        'fmamt' => $fmamt,
        'refdc' => '',
        'ftype' => $ftype,
        'sign'  => $sign,
        'fdesc' => $fdesc,
        'fdate' => $fdate,
        'fstat' => 'pending'
    ]);

    $fund->transid = date("ym").'01'.str_pad($fund->id, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);                
    $fund->save();        
    return $fund;
}
```